# ajax post to jsp receive null string

Tags: ajax, jsp, post

I am fetching data from a form using jquery and posting with ajax to a .jsp file.
when i try to receive the data in jsp scriplet using request.get parameter then i get null.

```
var values = {}; // Create empty javascript object
$("select").each(function() { // Iterate over selects
  values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).find(":selected").attr('data-citycode'); // Add each to features object
});
var format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
values["datepicker1"] = $("#datepicker1 div").datepicker("getFormattedDate", format);
values["datepicker2"] = $("#datepicker2 div").datepicker("getFormattedDate", format);

//var url ="list_flights.jsp";

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "list_flights.jsp",
  async: false,
  data: {
    values: JSON.stringify(values)
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    window.location = "list_flights.jsp";
  }
});
```

and the jsp scriplet

```
<% out.print(request.getParameter("values")); %>
```

> **output**
>   null

Comment: why on success `window.location = "list_flights.jsp";`

Answer (score 1):

it seems that on success of `ajax` you are changing the window location

```
success: function(data) {  
  console.log(data);  
  window.location = "list_flights.jsp";  
}
```

which is making another request and do not have the `values` attribute in request.

```
success: function(data) {  
  console.log(data);  
  window.location = "list_flights.jsp?values=" + JSON.stringify(values);  
}
```

But it doesn't make sense of redirecting on `success` and calling the `ajax` to the same jsp. You should call a servlet from ajax which will give you the response and based on that response you should redirect to another page.